# afer migrating to mongodb atlas db.once('open', () => {

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

after migrating my database from [Compose](https://www.compose.com/) to [Mongodb Altas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas). i changed the MONGO_URI to mongodb Altas and `db.once('open',` does not work

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  Promise = require('bluebird'),
  modelsPath = './models',
  glob = Promise.promisify(require('glob')),
  _ = require('lodash');

const models = () => glob(`${modelsPath}/**/*.js`);

module.exports = {
  init: () => {
    mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);

    let db = mongoose.connection;

    models()
      .then(m => {
        m.forEach(model => require(`../${model}`));

        db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Error connecting to mongodb: '));
        db.once('open', console.log.bind(console, 'Database connected.'));

        mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
      });
  }
};
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Personally, I had to use the old connection string for Atlas (The one _without_ the `mongo+srv://` prefix)

Comment: @MattyJ i remove the prefix but was now geting this error. MongoError: failed to connect to server [xxxxxx] on first connect [xxxxxxx]

Comment: The URL is completely different. You can’t just remove the prefix. It’s the UrL for a node app with driver version 2.2 and up (instead of 3.0 and up)